# Periods of prolonged inactivity and frequent MessageLockLostException in QueueClient

Tags: java, azure, azureservicebus, messaging

### Background

We have a data transfer solution with Azure Service Bus as the message broker. We are transferring data from `x` datasets through `x` queues - with `x` dedicated `QueueClient`s as senders. Some senders publish messages at the rate of one message every two seconds, while others publish one every 15 minutes.

The application on the data source side (where senders are) is working just fine, giving us the desired throughput.

On the other side, we have an application with one QueueClient receiver per queue with the following configuration:

- `maxConcurrentCalls` = `1`
- `autoComplete` = `true` (if receive mode = `RECEIVEANDDELETE`) and `false` (if receive mode = `PEEKLOCK`) - we have some receivers where, if they shut-down unexpectedly, would want to preserve the messages in the Service Bus Queue.
- `maxAutoRenewDuration` = `3` minutes (lock duraition on all queues = `30` seconds)
- an Executor service with a single thread

The `MessageHandler` registered with each of these receivers does the following:

```java
public CompletableFuture<Void> onMessageAsync(final IMessage message) {

    // deserialize the message body
    final CustomObject customObject = (CustomObject)SerializationUtils.deserialize((byte[])message.getMessageBody().getBinaryData().get(0));

    // process processDB1() and processDB2() asynchronously
    final List<CompletableFuture<Boolean>> processFutures = new ArrayList<CompletableFuture<Boolean>>();

    processFutures.add(processDB1(customObject));  // processDB1() returns Boolean
    processFutures.add(processDB2(customObject)); // processDB2() returns Boolean

    // join both the completablefutures to get the result Booleans
    List<Boolean> results = CompletableFuture.allOf(processFutures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[processFutures.size()])).thenApply(future -> processFutures.stream()
        .map(CompletableFuture<Boolean>::join).collect(Collectors.toList())

    if (results.contains(false)) {
        // dead-letter the message if results contains false
        return getQueueClient().deadLetterAsync(message.getLockToken());
    } else {
        // complete the message otherwise
        getQueueClient().completeAsync(message.getLockToken());
    }
}
```

We tested with the following scenarios:

### Scenario 1 - receive mode = `RECEIVEANDDELETE`, message publish rate: `30/ minute`

#### Expected Behavior

The messages should be received continuosuly with a constant throughput (which need not necessarily be the throughput at source, where messages are published).

#### Actual behavior

We observe random, long periods of inactivity from the QueueClient - ranging from minutes to hours - there is **no Outgoing Messages** from the Service Bus namespace (observed on the Metrics charts) and there are no consumption logs for the same time periods!

### Scenario 2 - receive mode = `PEEKLOCK`, message publish rate: `30/ minute`

#### Expected Behavior

The messages should be received continuosuly with a constant throughput (which need not necessarily be the throughput at source, where messages are published).

#### Actual behavior

We keep seeing `MessageLockLostException` constantly after 20-30 minutes into the run of the application.

We tried doing the following -

1. we reduced the prefetch count (from 20 * processing rate - as mentioned in the Best Practices guide) to a bare minimum (to even `0` in one test cycle), to reduce the no. of messages that are locked for the client
2. increased the `maxAutoRenewDuration` to 5 minutes - our `processDB1()` and `processDB2()` do not take more than a second or two for almost 90% of the cases - so, I think the lock duration of 30 seconds and `maxAutoRenewDuration` are not issues here.
3. removed the blocking `CompletableFuture.get()` and made the processing synchronous.

None of these tweaks helped us fix the issue. What we observed is that the `COMPLETE` or `RENEWMESSAGELOCK` are throwing the `MessageLockLostException`.

We need help with finding answers for the following:

1. **why is there a long period of inactivity of the `QueueClient` in scenario 1**?
2. **how do we know the `MessageLockLostException`s are thrown, because the locks have indeed expired**? we suspect the locks cannot expire too soon, as our processing happens in a second or two. disabling prefetch also did not solve this for us.

### Versions  and Service Bus details

- Java - `openjdk-11-jre`
- Azure Service Bus namespace tier: `Standard`
- Java SDK version - `3.4.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was not with the `QueueClient` object per se. It was with the processes that we were triggering from within the `MessageHandler`: `processDB1(customObject)` and `processDB2(customObject)`. since these processes were not optimized, the message consumption dropped and the locks gor expired (in peek-lock mode), as the handler was spending more time (in relation to the rate at which messages were published to the queues) in completing these opertations.

After optimizing the processes, the consumption and completion (in peek-lock mode) were just fine.

Answer (score 0):

**For Scenario 1 :**

If you have the [duplicate detection history](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/duplicate-detection) enabled, there is a possibility of this behavior happening as per the below explained scenario :

[image]

I had enabled for 30 seconds. I constantly hit Service bus with duplicate messages ( im my case messages with the same messageid from the client - 30 /per minute). I would be seeing a no activity outgoing for the window. Though the messages are received at the servicebus from the sending client, I was not be able to see them in outgoing messages. You could probably check whether you re encountering the duplicate messages which are filtered - inturn resulting inactivity in outgoing.

[image]

**Also Note** : You can't enable/disable duplicate detection after the queue is created. You can only do so at the time of creating the queue.

Comment: we did not have duplicate detection enabled. it was an issue with the processes that we were executing from the `MessageHandler`. we optimized those to fix this issue.